# Necessity of null-checking when accessing object properties with EL

Tags: html, jsp, null, jstl, el

I used to employ JSTL to test for `null` values before setting up HTML. But I ended up with a verbose code fragment:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${data == null}">
        <input type ='text'>
        <input type ='text'>
        <input type ='text'>
        <input type ='text'>
        <input type ='text'>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute1()}">
        <input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute2()}">
        <input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute3()}">
        <input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute4()}">
        <input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute5()}">
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But when I didn't use JSTL I still got the right HTML page without any errors and when the page was not invoking the controller, nothing seemed to be an issue. The code is presented below:

```
<input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute1()}">
<input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute2()}">
<input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute3()}">
<input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute4()}">
<input type ='text' value= "${data.getAttribute5()}">
```

Am I only wasting line of code to have these checks for `null`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to perform that check as you're reading a property via EL. This is so-called *null-safety* design feature of EL.

That said, this answer aims at explaining why this is the case. To recite [EL 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html), clause 1.6 regarding operator `.` (that is in turn equivalent to operator `[]`):

> **To evaluate** expr-a[expr-b] or **expr-a[expr-b] (params)**:
>
> - **Evaluate expr-a into value-a**;
> - **If value-a is null**:
>
>   - If expr-a[expr-b] is the last property being resolved:
>
>     - **If the expression is a value expression** and ValueExpression.getValue(context) was called to initiate this expression evaluation, **return null**;
>     - Otherwise, throw PropertyNotFoundException [trying to de-reference null for an lvalue];
>   - Otherwise, return null.

(emphasis mine).

As your expression `${data.getAttribute()}` is a value expression that uses the parameterized method call syntax in case `data == null` is true, `null` it will be returned as the result of `data.getAttribute()` evaluation. As soon as the output of this EL expression evaluation is a string, its value, `null` is coerced to `""` (empty string) as per clause 1.23.2 of EL 3.0 specification.

Also note that JSTL (the set of tags you use to build HTML like `<c:choose>`) *is not equal* to EL (the piece of code used to access and manipulate application data via `${expression}`). For more information consult [our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).